# Why is the distance in this metric space defined as it is?

Tags: probability-theory

From the book:

*Sidney I.Resnick, A Probability Path, 2005 Birhäuser Boston, 5th printing, page 79.*

''
Define the metric $d$ of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ by

$$d(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k}\dfrac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_i-y_i|}}{\displaystyle{1+\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_i-y_i|}}.$$

where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the $i$ th components of the vectors $\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ respectively.
''

I'm wondering why this metric is defined the way it is, it doesn't seem like a natural extension of finite dimensional Euclidean space. Is it defined this way to relate to something in statistics? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It is defined this way so that it is finite for any possible sequence in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Any natural extension of standard Euclidean metric likely fails for some extremely fast-growing sequences.

Comment: If $d_1,d_2,\dots$ satisfy all of the rules for a metric, except allowing zero values, and are bounded by the same upper bound, then $\sum_{k}2^{-k}d_k(x,y)$ satisfies the rules too. $2^{-1}$ can be replaced by any value $0<\alpha<1.$

Comment: Also, if $d(x,y)$  has these properties but not bounded, then $d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ has this property but is bounded. They key is that $d$ and $d',$ when $d$ is a full metric, yield the same topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X_k,d_k)$ be metric spaces with $d_k(x,y)<\alpha$ for some real $\alpha.$ Let $f_k:X\to X_k$ be a set of functions such that for all $x\neq y$ there is a $k$ such that $f_k(x)\neq f_k(y).$ Let $0<\beta<1.$

Then $$d(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta^k d_k(f_k(x),f_k(y))$$ is a metric.

Additionally, if $d(u,v)$ is a metric on a space $U,$ then $$d'(u,v)=\frac{d(u,v)}{1+d(u,v)}$$ is a metric, as well, and has the advantage that $d'(u,v)<1$ for all $u,v.$

From a topological point of view, $d$ and $d'$ define the same topology, so, while they are different metrics, they yield the same sets of continuous functions.

There are lots of ways to convert a metric to a topologically equivalent bounded metrics, but this is the simplest.

In your case $X=\mathbb R^\infty,$ $X_k=\mathbb R^k$ with the metric given by taking $d_k'$ where $d_k$ is the $L^1$ metric, and $f_k(x)=(x_i)_{i=1}^k.$

Then we have $\alpha=1,\beta=\frac12.$

---

Instead of the $L^1$ norm on $\mathbb R^k,$ you could have chosen any topologically equivalent norm, including $L^2$ and $L^\infty.$ The main reason to choose $L^1$ is that it is easier to write the final metric as a formula.

Similarly, instead of $d'=\frac d{1+d}$ we could have chosen another topologically equivalent bounded $d',$ but this one is the easiest to write out.

Basically, we are choosing this metric to satisfy a topological property.

So, all of these choices are arbitrary ones from a whole slew of choices, all made here to be as simple to write out as possible.

---

The real question is, why choose these $X_k,d_k$ when you could choose a much simpler example where each $X_k=\mathbb R$ and you get:

$$d(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{1+|x_k-y_k|}$$

What does the original metric give you that this one does not?

The only advantage I see in the original is that $d_k(f_k(x),f_k(y))$ is an increasing function there.

Comment: Regarding your question about why $d_k$ is defined in that summation form in this formula, I looked at a proposition in the book about this, so maybe that provides some motivation.

The metric space $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty},d)$ defined as above, if a map $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ provide

$$
X^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{F}\text{ for all }E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}),
$$

then $X$ is call a *random sequence*, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is a pair consisting a set and a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$ is called a *measurable space*,

Comment: and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ is the minimal $\sigma$-field generated by 
the set of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, $X^{-1}(E)$ is a inverse image of $E$.

Similarly, replace $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}))$ into finite dimensional with Eulidean distance, $X$ is called a *random vector*. 

It's easy to see that for any two metric spaces $(S,d)$ and $(S',d')$, a continuous map $g:S\to S'$ satisfies:

$$g^{-1}(\mathcal{O}')\in\mathcal{B}(S)\text{ for all open sets }\mathcal{O}'\subset S'.$$

since $g^{-1}(\mathcal{O}')$ is an open set in $S$.

Comment: For any two measuable spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}),(\Omega',\mathcal{F}')$ , if a map $X:\Omega\to\omega'$ provide:

$$X^{-1}(E')\in\mathcal{F}\text{ for all }E'\in\mathcal{F}',$$

then $X$ is called a *random element*. As you can see, both random vector (one dimonsional random vector is called random variable) and random squence are random element, any composition of two random element is a random element. In particular, if we choose $g$ to be the projection $\pi_{i}:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$, then $\pi_i\circ X$ is a random variable for any random vector $X$, and we can prove that

Comment: $X:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ is a random vector iff $\pi_i\circ X$ is a random variable for all $i=1,2,\dots,k$. Hence we can simply denote $X=(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_k)$, where $X_i:=\pi_i\circ X$. Similar to random sequence.

Here's the proposition:

"$X=(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ is a random sequence iff for each $i=1,2,\dots$ the $i$ th component $X_i$ is a random variable. Furthermore, $X$ is a random sequence iff $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is a random vector, for any $k$."

In light of this proposition, is it possible to explain why d_k is defined in summation form?

Answer (score 4):

You can't really "naturally extend" the metric of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, since given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$ given as above, the expression

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i$

doesn't make sense/doesn't converge. How could we fix this? Well, appending negative powers as two to terms usually helps convergence, so we could try

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}x_i y_i$

But this doesn't work either. Take fx $x=(1,1,1,...)$ and $y$ with $y_i=2^{2^{i}}$. But if we could bound the terms comming from the coordinates of the inputs, the negative powers of $2$ would make the series convergent. And since

$\dfrac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^k |x_i-y_i|}}{\displaystyle{1 + \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i-y_i|}}<1$

we get a convergent series, and hence an at least well defined function. Proving it's a metric is left as an exercise :).

Comment: Thank you! I think I am fully understand it. ( •̀ ω •́ )✧

Comment: Sorry, what metric is $\sum_i x_iy_i$? Also, if one assumes $x=0$, then there's no convergence problem.

Comment: @Dog_69 Good point with $x=0$, fixed that. And summing over the pairwise products of entries is not a metric, just the naive attempt to "naturally extend" the euclidean metric.

Comment: @RichardJensen Ok. I understand now. You were describing the inner product from which the metric would be defined.

Comment: Oh, haha, you're completely right, what I wrote is nonsense...

Comment: @PauseAndPonder Consider checking out Thomas Andrew's answer above, it's waay better!